# Probability of Getting Favorite Marble

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Suppose there are 5 marbles, and person One has a favorite marble and person Two has a favorite marble. Each person a list of which marbles they like the best. If person One comes and removes 2 of his least preferred marbles, and then person Two comes and removes 2 of his least preferred marbles from the remaining 3, what's the probability that the remaining marble is no ones top choice?

The way I approached it is $ 5 \choose 2 $$*$$3 \choose 2$, but I'm not really sure what the denominator will be. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is asking what is the probability that Person One's favourite was removed by Person Two *and* Person Two's favourite was removed by Person One.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the remaining marble to be neither $1$'s top choice nor $2$'s top choice, the two marbles that $1$ removes must include $2$'s top choice.

$2$'s top choice could be any of the give marbles with equal probability, and $1$ removes two of the five marbles. This means that the probability that $2$'s top choice is removed is $$\frac{2}{5}$$

Given this, $1$'s top choice is one of the remaining three marbles, and $2$ must remove it. The probability that $1$'s top choice is removed is therefore $$\frac{2}{3}$$

The final answer is the product of the probabilities of these two events that must both occur:

$$\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \,=\,\boxed{\frac{4}{15}\,} \, = \, 0.2\overline{6}$$